# jQuery reel don't allow reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-reel

I want to force my reel animation to always go forward and never in reverse (i.e. the animation frame number should only every get larger and never be allowed to get smaller).

Is there a sensible way to do this?

**Edit for clarity:**

I am using [jQuery reel](http://reel360.org/reel) to create a simple animation. The animation is made up of 10 images (01.png, 02.png, 03.png ...). The default behavior of reel is to play the animation when the user clicks / touches on the image and drags left or right.

When the user drags to the right it plays the animation in the correct sequence -- essentially advancing from 01.png, 02.png, 03.png ... No issues here.

When the user drags to the left it plays the animation in reverse -- 03.png, 02.png, 01.png, 10.png, 09.png ... I don't like this and I want to disable it.

So I'm looking for a way to only allow the animation to be played in "forward mode" and disable "reverse mode". In other words I'd like to be able to disable dragging to the left or panning to the left.

Does this make sense?

Comment: What are you talking about???

Comment: haha, I guess this is just a bad question in general :-) I'll try to rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the X or Y position in the "pan" event and return false if it is less than the X or Y position on "down" like this

```
$('#your_reel_image').on('down', function(e, x, y, ev){
    $(this).data("lastPosition",{"x":x,"y":y});//store the position on mousedown
}).on('pan', function(e,x,y,ev){//event when you do a mousemove while the mousedown
    var $reel=$(this);
    var delta=$reel.data("lastPosition").x-x;//difference between current and last position
    if(delta<0){
        $reel.data("lastPosition",{"x":x,"y":y});//update position
        $reel.data("direction","right");//set current direction to right
    }
    else if(delta>0){
        $reel.data("direction","left");//set current direction to left
        return false;//prevent the reverse animation
    }
});
```

i also add a function in fractionChange to prevent the 1 frame reverse animation that will happen if you only move the cursor to the left

```
$('#your_reel_image').on('fractionChange',function(){
    if($(this).data("direction")=="left"){//if the current direction is left
        $(this).data("direction","")//clear the current direction
        return false;//return false prevent the 1 frame animation 
        //without the last line you can return 1 frame at a time on mouseup 
    }
});
```

if you want to prevent the reverse animation on mousewheel you need to add this function

```
$('#your_reel_image').on('wheel',function(e, distance, ev){
    var $reel=$(this);
    //almost the same as in the pan function without storing the position
    if(distance<0){
        $reel.data("direction","right");
    }
    else if(distance>0){
        $reel.data("direction","left");
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N68qa/1/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for such a complete answer.